# updating node attributes in xml using php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Is it possible to update the node attributes of an xml using simplexml? 
example:-my program is actually a quiz editor for teacher, as a teacher, i want to edit a specific question attributes. ie

```
<Quiz>
<topic text="Preparation for Exam">
    <subtopic text="Math">
              <question text="1 + 1 = ?"> 
              <answer num="A" Text="1" /> 
              <answer num="B" Text="2" /> 
              <answer num="C" Text="3" /> 
              <answer num="D" Text="4" /> 
              </question>
              <question text="4 * 4 = ?" > 
              <answer num="A" Text="12" /> 
              <answer num="B" Text="14" /> 
              <answer num="C" Text="16" /> 
              <answer num="D" Text="18" /> 
              </question>
       </subtopic>
       </topic>
       </Quiz>
```

is it possible? though i have tried a lot of ways ie by deleting the previous node and then inserting the edited one. but this trick only works for last node... for other nodes it just do swapping

Comment: come on guys.... need help here ....

Comment: You could also try with phpQuery class instead of SimpleXML.

Comment: yeah. go ahead sir, i'll be glad to see the the codes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$subtopic = new SimpleXMLELement(data());
$subtopic->question[1]['text'] = 'lalala';
$subtopic->question[1]['foo'] = 'bar';

foreach( $subtopic->question[1]->answer as $answer) {
    $answer['Text'] .= '(dez)';
}

echo $subtopic->asXML();


function data() {
    return <<< eox
<subtopic text="Math">
<question text="1 + 1 = ?"> 
<answer num="A" Text="1" /> 
<answer num="B" Text="2" /> 
<answer num="C" Text="3" /> 
<answer num="D" Text="4" /> 
</question>
<question text="4 * 4 = ?" > 
<answer num="A" Text="12" /> 
<answer num="B" Text="14" /> 
<answer num="C" Text="16" /> 
<answer num="D" Text="18" /> 
</question>
</subtopic>
eox;
}
```

prints

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<subtopic text="Math">
<question text="1 + 1 = ?"> 
<answer num="A" Text="1"/> 
<answer num="B" Text="2"/> 
<answer num="C" Text="3"/> 
<answer num="D" Text="4"/> 
</question>
<question text="lalala" foo="bar"> 
<answer num="A" Text="12(dez)"/> 
<answer num="B" Text="14(dez)"/> 
<answer num="C" Text="16(dez)"/> 
<answer num="D" Text="18(dez)"/> 
</question>
</subtopic>
```

Comment: Sir, Is it possible to change the question along with the answers at the same time using your codes? @VolkerK

Comment: Sir, i am getting some silly errors.... the name of my xml file is 'questions.xml'? i have rewritten the complete structure of my xml code. Can you give it a try in defining the path for the question to be edited? please ..thanks